# MYSQL SLOW replication but suddenly increasing and then again slow in mysql Slave unable

Tags: mysql, database-performance, mysql-error-1064, database-administration, slave

I am facing a major issue in MySQL server from 2 days. My slave server is Seconds behind master by 70000 and its not getting down from 2 days. At night its suddenly increasing but again it in slow mode. Is there any way to Synchronize Master slave replication FAST? What is the problem with? Slave is working its IO and sql running in YES MODE. Please Help me out if there is any way

Answer (score 1):

Is it repeatedly bouncing between 70000 and about 0?  If so, that is a mystery that I have seen on and off for more than a decade.  Ignore it, it will go away.

If Seconds_behind_master is rising at the rate of 1 second per second, the look at what the Slave is doing.  `SHOW PROCESSLIST;`  You will probably find something like `ALTER` that has been running a long time, tying up replication.

If Seconds_behind_master is getting big, but not going down much, then there are several possible answers.

Is the Slave a "weaker" machine than the Master?  Keep in mind that Replication is (depending on the version) only single-threaded.  Multiple writes can happen on the Master simultaneously, but then have to be done one at a time on the Slave.

Is the Slave running a big query that is locking what the replication thread would like to get to?  Look at the Slave's PROCESSLIST.

Which Engine are you using?  VM?  Cloud hosted?  Performing backups at night?